# Is it possible to build a native macOS with Node.js in Xcode?

Tags: node.js, xcode

I want build a macOS web app with GUI that scrapes webpages, handles HTTP requests and takes advantage of macOS features.

Comment: You can’t build a native macOS app with Node because JavaScript is not a native language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately no, since Xcode is Apple's native IDE and can only utilize Objective-C and Swift.